# Observable with async pipe doesn't update UI Angular 4

Tags: angular, asynchronous, observable

I am having simple set of data loaded into `observable` as below:

```
public tasks: Observable<UserTask[]>;
constructor(private dataService: HttpdataService, private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.loadTasks();
}

loadTasks() {
  this.tasks = this.dataService.loadTasks(someurl);
}

completeTasks(task: UserTask, url: string) {
  this.dataService.finishTasks(url, task.id).then(() => {
     this.toastr.success('Task completed successfully!', 'Success');
         this.tasks.subscribe(() => {
         this.changeDetector.markForCheck();
     });
  }).catch(err => {
    this.toastr.error('The request has errored out!', 'Error');
    console.error(err);
  });
}
```

My UI looks like

```
<tr *ngFor="let task of tasks | async">
   //td data
</tr>
```

**completeTasks()** will be called on a button click and executes successfully But the UI is never updated after completing the task operation. Using `ChangeDetectionRef` was my last option to try. I tried to run the operation using `ngZone` but couldn't succeed.

When I write `this.tasks.subscribe()` and `console.log` the data, I see that task has been removed from Observable but yea not UI update. What else I can try. Could someone please point me right direction.

**Update**

Here's the method within `dataservice`:

```
loadTasks(ep: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(ep + '/usertask');
}
```

Comment: hello, could you show us code of `this.dataService.loadTasks(someurl)` ?

Comment: are you using ChangeDetection.OnPush?

Comment: @TomaszKula OnPush detection are award from observable.next. i suspect  loadTasks to simple API call from HttpClient. If yes, after first next, is never updated when tasks change.

Comment: @Yanis-git Yes its simple `HttpClient` request. Updated my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need `Observable` self managed and dedicated for `task list lifecycle`.

Attached example with `BehaviorSuject` and `TaskService`. For this example, instead to load from ajax request, i just populate dummy data after 1 secs.

Then you have update / delete action who both have to update list according to action done by user.

**Component.ts :**

```
import {
    Component,  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';

import {TaskModel, TaskService} from './services/task.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(public taskService: TaskService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.taskService.fetchTask();
    }

    onChangeHandler(task: TaskModel)
    {
        this.taskService.save(task);
    }

    onDeleteHandler(task: TaskModel) {
        this.taskService.remove(task);
    }
}
```

Here we just manage view and ask service according to action (or lifecycle hook). On init we want to load from server, then if checkbox is changing, we want to update our reference, when we click on delete button, we want to remove from list (and may on server as well).

**component.html**

```
<h2>TODO LIST</h2>
<div *ngFor="let task of (taskService.task$ | async)">
    <p>
        {{ task.title }} | <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="task.status" (change)="onChangeHandler(task)"> | <button (click)="onDeleteHandler(task)"> Delete </button>
    </p>
</div>
```

now main code is on **task.service** :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {isUndefined} from 'util';

export interface TaskModel {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    status: boolean;
}

@Injectable()
export class TaskService {
    /**
     * Observable who should always be the replica of last tasks state.
     */
    private _tasks$: BehaviorSubject<TaskModel[]>;
    /**
     * array of task, use for each action done on task.
     */
    private tasks: TaskModel[];

    constructor() {
        // We init by empty array.
        this._tasks$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);
        this.tasks = [];
    }

    /**
     * Fake fetch data from server.
     */
    fetchTask()
    {
        // Fake request.
        Observable.create(obs => {
            /**
             * After 1 secs, we update internal array and observable.
             */
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.tasks = this.getDummyData();
                obs.next(this.tasks);
            }, 1000);

        }).subscribe(state => this._tasks$.next(state));
    }

    /**
     * Magic getter
     * @return {Observable<{id: number; title: string; status: boolean}[]>}
     */
    get task$(): Observable<TaskModel[]> {
        // return only observable, don't put public your BehaviorSubject
        return this._tasks$.asObservable();
    }

    /**
     * We update from internal array reference, and we next fresh data with our observable.
     * @param {TaskModel} task
     */
    save(task: TaskModel) {
        const index = this.tasks.findIndex(item => item.id === task.id);
        if(!isUndefined(this.tasks[index]))
        {
            this.tasks[index] = task;
        }

        // Notify rest of application.
        this._tasks$.next(this.tasks);
    }

    /**
     * We remove from internal array reference, and we next data with our observable.
     * @param {TaskModel} task
     */
    remove(task: TaskModel) {
        this.tasks = this.tasks.filter(item => item.id !== task.id);
        this._tasks$.next(this.tasks);
    }

    /**
     * Fake data.
     * @return {{id: number; title: string; status: boolean}[]}
     */
    private getDummyData() : TaskModel[]
    {
        return [
            {
                id: 1,
                title: 'task1',
                status: true
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                title: 'task2',
                status: false
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                title: 'task3',
                status: true
            }
        ];
    }
}
```

[Online code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jnz5ao?file=app%2Ftask.service.ts)

Comment: Awesome Yanis.. Thanks for such a beautiful explanation.. :)

Comment: My please @GuruprasadRao, happy coding :)